# How can i take certain values from a CSV file, search for the values in the csv file and graph + and - 1 around each value in separate graphs?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I am quite new to python so please bear with me.

I have quite a large csv file, I have chosen certain values that are outside a range.

Here is the code for choosing the values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv", skiprows=[1])
magnitudes = df['Magnitude '].values
times = df['Time '].values
zscores = np.abs(stats.zscore(magnitudes, ddof=1))
outlier_indicies = np.argwhere(zscores > 3).flatten()
numbers = print(times[outlier_indicies])
```

The values printed are below.

```
 2455338.895 2455350.644 2455391.557 2455404.776 2455413.734 2455451.661
 2455473.49  2455477.521 2455507.505 2455702.662 2455734.597 2455765.765
 2455776.575 2455826.593 2455842.512 2455866.508 2455996.796 2456017.767
 2456047.694 2456058.732 2456062.722 2456071.924 2456082.802 2456116.494
 2456116.535 2456116.576 2456116.624 2456116.673 2456116.714 2456116.799
 2456123.527 2456164.507 2456166.634 2456391.703 2456455.535 2456455.6
 2456501.763 2456511.616 2456519.731 2456525.49  2456547.588 2456570.526
 2456595.515 2456776.661 2456853.543 2456920.511 2456953.496 2457234.643
 2457250.68  2457252.672 2457278.526 2457451.89  2457485.722 2457497.93
 2457500.674 2457566.874 2457567.877 2457644.495 2457661.553 2457675.513
```

An example of the csv file is this:

```
     Time        Magnitude   Magnitude error 
  2455260.853      19.472             0.150
  2455260.900      19.445             0.126
  2455261.792      19.484             0.168
  2455262.830      19.157             0.261
  2455264.814      19.376             0.150
...           ...         ...               ...
  2457686.478      19.063             0.176
  2457689.480      19.178             0.128
  2457690.475      19.386             0.171
  2457690.480      19.092             0.112
  2457691.476      19.191             0.122.
```

I am trying to take one of the values, for example, 2455404.776, + and - 1 from it, grab all the values within the +- 1 of the value in the csv file, and create a graph for each one of the values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

PS: I am happy to share my CSV file,

Comment: what is your problem? selecting the correct things? graphing them?

Comment: I am having trouble selecting the range of +-  1 and graphing it. @PatrickArtner

Comment: @aaronHuang, Could you share a portion of the csv? I think I can put together an example modified data frame and graph for you with that

I'm assuming you want to focus on the `time` values and then calculate +/- 1.000 around a given `time`? Then create a new df with those figures and graph. Lastly, for your graph: your modified df needs at least two columns to create a graph, I don't see that in the way you have your code currently set up - i.e. `magnitudes` and `time`.  We'll use df w/ the `plt.plot(Your_modified_df['selection-to-plot'])`